# Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Existe diferença entre *`$(document).ready() e window.onload`* além de um ser JavaScript e o outro ser jQuery?

Vejo que ambos os eventos são disparados assim que o ***[DOM](https://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/) (Modelo de Objetos do Documento)*** é carregado.

Na prática como são escritos:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});


window.onload = function() {

};
```

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: @JefersonLeonardo não quer tentar uma resposta?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

O evento [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) é disparado depois que o documento HTML foi carregado.

O [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) só é disparado quando **todo** o conteúdo é carregado (incluindo imagens, vídeos, etc).

Repare que o `ready` é específico do jQuery. Isto é, ele não existe "nativamente". A intenção dele é executar algo o mais rápido possível depois de carregar o documento, sem precisar esperar todo o conteúdo ser carregado.

Exemplo do `document.ready` usando uma imagem pesada

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('Ready disparado');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Meu conteúdo</div>
<img src="http://joumxyzptlk.de/pics/normal/unigine/Unigine%20Valley%2010k%20(10240x5760)%20-%20000.jpg" />
```

Exemplo do `onload`

```js
window.onload = function(){
  console.log('Onload disparado');
}
```

```html
<div>Meu conteúdo</div>

<img src="http://joumxyzptlk.de/pics/normal/unigine/Unigine%20Valley%2010k%20(10240x5760)%20-%20000.jpg" />
```

O evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) tem a mesma intenção do `ready`.

Ex.:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM completamente carregado e analisado");
});

for(var i=0; i< 1000000000; i++)
{}
```

```html
<div>Meu conteúdo</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

O evento `ready` ocorre depois que o documento HTML foi carregado, enquanto o evento `onload` ocorre mais tarde, quando todo o conteúdo (por exemplo, imagens) também foi carregado.

O evento `onload` é um evento padrão no DOM, enquanto o evento `ready` é específico para jQuery. O objetivo do evento `ready` é que ele deve ocorrer o mais cedo possível após o documento ser carregado, para que o código que adiciona a funcionalidade para os elementos na página não precisar esperar todo o conteúdo para carregar.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)