# Verificar carregamento de arquivo externo com JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Minha home page possui um vídeo como background porém em alguns momentos o vídeo demora para ser carregado. Nesta situação pensei em criar um `loading` antes da pagina ser exibida, minha duvida é de como posso verificar com o `jquery/javascript` se um arquivo (vídeo) já foi carregado completamente para então exibir a pagina por inteira.

O video é um arquivo local

```
<video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="/public/video/capa_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Em minha pagina estou usando o plugin [`fullpage js`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js), então em meu arquivo `.js` já possuo a função `ready`do `jquery`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Como posso fazer para exibir um efeito de load antes do documento ser todo carregado (imagens, videos, fonts e etc) ?

Comment: Não consegue com o evento `window.onload`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss algumas vezes a pagina é carregada porém o video ainda não foi carregado completamente, logo, ele trava em algum ponto.

Comment: Talvez possa te [ajudar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182797/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-document-ready-e-window-onload/182803#182803)!

Comment: Pelo o que ele disse, o evento `onload` pode ser disparado antes do vídeo ser carregado por completo (talvez seria por quê o vídeo não é transferido de uma vez e sim *streamado*?)

Comment: Põe uma div cobrindo o conteúdo e um gif animado de loading e usa o window.onload pra esconder essa div quando a página for carregada por completo. (Veja link do Marconi no comentário acima que leva até a resposta do Jbueno em outra pergunta).

Comment: Poẽm o código junto a pergunta e especifique melhor o ambiente. O vídeo exibido é local ou do YouTube/etc?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss melhorei a pergunta

Answer (score 3):

Conforme alguns exemplos que encontrei na web, apenas utilizar o evento `window.onload` para ocultar a `div` de carregamento nem sempre é suficiente, pois em conexões mais lentas, o vídeo pode não estar pronto para a execução quando tal evento é disparado.

A forma mais prática que encontrei foi a deste [site](http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/web-development/check-when-an-html5-video-has-loaded/):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('#video');
    var preloader = document.querySelector('.preloader');

    function checkLoad() {
        if (video.readyState === 4) {
            preloader.parentNode.removeChild(preloader);
        } else {
            setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
        }
    }

    checkLoad();
}, false);
```

Em que é executada a função `checkLoad` no evento `window.load`, porém, caso o vídeo ainda não esteja suficientemente pronto, ele volta a fazer a verificação 100 ms mais tarde, com a função `setTimeout`.

A verificação do estado do vídeo, no caso `video.readyState === 4`, é baseada na tabela abaixo, tirada deste [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState). Tradução livre: se retornado 4, já há dados disponíveis suficientes - e a velocidade da conexão é alta o bastante - então o vídeo poderá ser executado até o final sem interrupções.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O **onload** só é executado após todo conteúdo da página ser carregado.

Testei com um vídeo seguindo o link do Marconi para a resposta do Jbueno.

Segue o exemplo:

```js
window.onload=function()
{  document.getElementById("loading").style.display='none';
}
```

```css
    #loading{
 color:#fff; 
 background-color:#000; 
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; 
 left:0;
 z-index:9999;
 }
```

```html
<div id="loading">Carregando...</div>

Página carregada.
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: A dúvida que fiquei é: o HTML5 transfere de uma só vez o vídeo assim como faz com a imagem ou vai transferindo os frames conforme o vídeo é executado, tal como o YouTube faz? Neste segundo caso, acredito que o evento é disparado antes do vídeo ser carregado por completo.

Comment: Mudei o código para um vídeo exibido com html5. Só esconde a div depois que o vídeo foi carregado.

Comment: Testei com uma velocidade menor de internet e o "loading" não aparece, a tela fica branca, e só quando o site carrega o loading aparece rapidamente e depois já troca para o video.
Como posso fazer para exibir o loading antes de tudo?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly tente colocando a _tag_ do _loading_ logo após a abertura da _tag_ `<body>` e com o CSS embutido na _tag_ pelo atributo `style`;

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer isso com vídeo, de forma mais rustica, é ficar verificando o status dele, e quando o status for `4`, significa que ele foi carregado por completo:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
   if (video.readyState === 4) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Carregado!';
   }
}, 500);
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls id="video">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<p id="status"></p>
```