# Erro ao chamar 2 Funções javascript ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu preciso chamar essas duas funções separadas como esta o código só que só uma funciona como faço para as duas funcionar?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

        if ('a' == 'a')

        {
           document.getElementById("nomeprodut").innerHTML = "Altera nome do produto";
        } 

    }
</script>

<div id="nomeprodut"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function() {

        if ('b' == 'b')

        {
           document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "grghgh";
        } 

    }
</script>

<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: Posso estar errado, mais o evento onload so ocorre 1 vez, e por isso so chama a ultima funcao que definiu como `onload`, se nao me engano o ultimo sobrescreve o anterior. Sem colocar tudo no mesmo `onload` ou pelo menos en funcoes separadas acho que nao tem como.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira Concerteza deve ser esse o problema mesmo, a pagina gera cada javascript separado, teria como eu fazer uma função igual essa sem onload sera?

Comment: Algum motivo especial para estar carregando varios JSs com um onload em cada um, nao tem como mover tudo pra um lugar so?

Comment: @Josimara fiz uma pergunta recente sobre [onload](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182797/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-document-ready-e-window-onload), talvez a outra função possa te ajudar!

Comment: @NeuberOliveira Tenho uma pagina que gera uma lista de produtos, cada produto gera um javascript, só posso utilizar html/javascript

Comment: @Marconi Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, thanks...

Comment: @Josimara bom que pude ajudar :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode adicionar mais de uma function ao mesmo evento, e ele será executado uma vez no caso do `onload`, mas executará todas as funções na ordem que você adicionar usando `addEventListener`. Documentação aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Basicamente, você faz o seguinte:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(event) {
    if ('a' == 'a') {
    document.getElementById("nomeprodut").innerHTML = "Altera nome do produto";
  }
},false);
```

e depois:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(event) {
  if ('b' == 'b') {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "grghgh"; 
  }
},false);
```

E assim por diante, pode adicionar outros listener para o evento load.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro usar o evento DOMContentLoaded, que é executado após todo o conteúdo ser carregado. Veja um exemplo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function a() {
        alert('a');
        if ('a' == 'a')
        {
           document.getElementById("nomeprodut").innerHTML = "Altera nome do produto";
        } 
    }
</script>
<div id="nomeprodut"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function b() {
        alert('b');
        if ('b' == 'b')

        {
           document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "grghgh";
        } 
    }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    a();
    b();
});

</script>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque tudo dentro de um `onload` somente, ficando assim:

```
<div id="nomeprodut"></div>
<div id="b"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  if ('a' == 'a') {
    document.getElementById("nomeprodut").innerHTML = "Altera nome do produto";
  }
  if ('b' == 'b') {
    document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = "grghgh"; 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: O Problema é que a pagina gera o javascript para cada produto em meu site dai preciso separado, ou tem alguma maneira de fazer sem onload?

Comment: Uma solução seria não utilizar o `onload`, porém pode ter o risco do script executar antes mesmo da renderização do HTML, o que ocasionaria em erros, por não encontrar o elemento na página. Mas tem que testar pra ver. Outra forma é usar o `setTimeout` antes de alterar o conteúdo dos elementos da página, é uma solução "não elegante", mas que pode funcionar. Já outro ponto, é verificar a necessidade de gerar um código Javascript para cada produto na página e sim pensar em outras formas de fazer isso, algo mais global do que específico de cada produto.

Comment: O Problema é que só posso fazer essa função usando html/js, se fosse php não teria esse problema, vou experimentatar o setTimeout, colocando só a a função sem o onload não funciona a codigo