# Dúvida sobre código padronizado JS

Tags: javascript

Olá, queria entender porque esse código javascript segue essa padronização, peguei um projeto e percebi que todos os arquivos js segue esse padrão

```
var projeto = {
    methods: {
        funcao1: function() {

        },
        funcao2: function() {

        },
        init: function() {
            this.funcao1(), this.funcao2()
        },
        init_ajax: function() {}
    },
    ajax: function() {
        return this.methods.init_ajax()
    },
    mounted: function() {
        return this.methods.init()
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    projeto.mounted()
}), $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    projeto.ajax()
});
```

Comment: Eu posso estar erro, por isso prefiro apenas comentar.. Acredito que o dev tenha feito assim por simplesmente ser mais pratico para ele e tentou criar um proprio padrao, sabe?

Comment: @DavidDias Então isso seria mais um padrão de organização? e aquela parte final do codigo qual a função dela?

Comment: Tentei explicar trecho a trecho na resposta para ver se te ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui ele criou uma especie de classe, na verdade um objeto com funções. Assim ele pode centralizar o que o `projeto` pode fazer e utilizar em qualquer outro lugar.

```
var projeto = {
    methods: {
        funcao1: function() {

        },
        funcao2: function() {

        },
        init: function() {
            this.funcao1(), this.funcao2()
        },
        init_ajax: function() {}
    },
    ajax: function() {
        return this.methods.init_ajax()
    },
    mounted: function() {
        return this.methods.init()
    }
};
```

Isso `$(document)` pega o documento propriamente dito, o que for lido pelo navegador. O que ele faz com o `.ready()` e `ajaxStop()` é pegar os eventos disparados pelo document nos momentos que o documento é lido e alguma chamada ajax é finalizada, respectivamente.

Com isso, ele definiu metodos que devem ser executados nesses momentos.

Quando o documento for lido (pagina carregada) executar `projeto.mounted()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    projeto.mounted()
})
```

Quando o carregamento ajax parar, execute `projeto.ajax()`

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    projeto.ajax()
});
```

Perceba que `projeto` é a variável que possui os metodos `ajax` e `mounted`.

Você provavelmente já deve ter utilizado algo como `element.on('click')` ou `element.click()` para capturar os cliques de botões ou algo assim, o processo aqui é o mesmo, porém, ao invés de captura o click, você esta `capturando` outras coisas. Poderia ser um hover, um keyup, etc.

Vou listar alguns links aqui que vão ajudar na compreensão geral, sua duvida e boa e vai ajudar bastante gente.

1. [Trabalhando com eventos em JavaScript](https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-eventos-em-javascript/28521)
2. [Organizando seu código JavaScript](http://shipit.resultadosdigitais.com.br/blog/proteja-seus-metodos-organizando-seu-codigo-javascript/)
3. [Sobre o document.ready](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182803/21836)

Comment: Entendido valeuu!

Answer (score 1):

E difícil uma resposta precisa pois nenhum desenvolvedor é obrigado a seguir padrões estabelecidos ou sugeridos, e pode criar seu próprio padrão. Isso na verdade é essencial para o próprio crescimento e desenvolvimento das tecnologias.

É graças a aqueles que recusaram um padrão anterior e criaram um novo, julgando ser melhor, é que temos os novos frameworks e bibliotecas.

O que é possível deduzir ou interpretar do código que você informou é:

1. Foi criado um único objeto JavaScript para conter todas as ações do
   projeto (var projeto = {...)
2. A propriedade "methods" provavelmente deve conter todos os métodos, eventos e ações do projeto
3. A propriedade "ajax" é executada sempre que uma requisição AJAX é finalizada. Como liberar a tela de algum bloqueio ou indicação de "Carregando...".
4. A propriedade "mounted" é a primeira a ser executada quando a página e carregada, neste caso está chamando apenas o método "init".
5. Na inicialização do jQuery, contém apenas as configurações de inicialização do projeto (chamada projeto.mounted()) e da finalização das requisições ajax (chamada projeto.ajax())

Comment: Valeu bem explicado!

Answer (score 1):

A indentação e o espaçamento entre colchetes normalmente definem o padrão da estruturação do código.

No desenvolvimento pode ser usada como referencia para tornar o código mais "limpo" e legível seguindo o mesmo padrão.

Algumas ferramentas podem ser incorporadas a editores de texto para ajudar nesta busca por uma padronização, umas com padrões mais "rígidos" e outras mais "flexíveis" permitindo ao usuário (o programador) estilizar o padrão.

Isto é útil no desenvolvimento, em produção o remondado é utilizar "compressão" para diminuir a carga sobre a requisição do recurso.

Quanto ao código: é apenas um fragmento que utiliza `jQuery`.

A primeira chamada ocorre no evento `DOMContentLoaded` e chama algumas funções no objeto.

Já `.ajaxStop()` é uma função `jQuery` usada normalmente para obeservar o fim de chamadas `AJAX` (ou disparar alguma função ao término destas chamadas)

```js
try {
    var projeto = {
        methods: {
            funcao1: function() {
                console.log('função 001')
            },
            funcao2: function() {
                console.log('função 002')
            },
            init: function() {
                this.funcao1(), this.funcao2()
            },
            init_ajax: function() {}
        },
        ajax: function() {
            return this.methods.init_ajax()
        },
        mounted: function() {
            return this.methods.init()
        }
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        projeto.mounted()
    }), $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        projeto.ajax()
    });
} catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Valeu por ajudar!