# JQuery.text nao funciona

Tags: jquery

Nao estao vazias, mas nao consigo colocar o texto dentro das divs

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Relógio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="relogio" class="fundo">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="horas"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="minutos"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="segundos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.fundo {
    background-color: bisque;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    padding-top: 15%;
}

.caixa {
    background-color: burlywood;
    color: black;
    font-size: 8em;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    border: solid 5px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
var $horas = $('#horas'),
    $minutos = $('#minutos'),
    $segundos = $('#segundos');

function pegaHora(){
    var data = new Date();

    var horas = data.getHours() < 10
            ? '0' + data.getHours()
            : data.getHours();

    var minutos = data.getMinutes() < 10
            ? '0' + data.getMinutes()
            : data.getMinutes()

    var segundos = data.getSeconds() < 10
            ? '0' + data.getSeconds()
            : data.getSeconds();

    //alert(horas + minutos + segundos);
    $horas.text("dafuck");
    $minutos.text(minutos);
    $segundos.text(segundos);
}

pegaHora();
window.setInterval(pegaHora, 1000);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que seu script esta dentro do arquivo `index.js`.
Ao invés de incluir ele dentro do `<head>` coloque ele antes do `</body>`, igual você fez com o `bootstrap.min.js`.

---

Provavelmente, não esta funcionando porque você esta criando as variáveis

```
var $horas = $('#horas'),
    $minutos = $('#minutos'),
    $segundos = $('#segundos');
```

em um momento em que o `html` ainda não foi carregado, no `<head>`, então o **jQuery** não vai encontrar seu *selector*.
Como a criação dessas variáveis esta fora da função `pegaHora`, que é chamada com `setInterval`, elas vão ficar com um **jQuery sem resultado** para sempre.

---

Outra possível solução e colocar seu script para executar dentro de um dos eventos `$(document).ready` ou `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){

   /// seu script

};

/// ou 

$(document).ready(function(){

   /// seu script

});
```

[Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182803/3774)

Answer (score 1):

Então, não sei qual ambiente está testando, mas, como pode ver abaixo, está funcionando normalmente:

```js
var $horas = $('#horas'),
  $minutos = $('#minutos'),
  $segundos = $('#segundos');

function pegaHora() {
  var data = new Date();

  var horas = data.getHours() < 10 ?
    '0' + data.getHours() :
    data.getHours();

  var minutos = data.getMinutes() < 10 ?
    '0' + data.getMinutes() :
    data.getMinutes()

  var segundos = data.getSeconds() < 10 ?
    '0' + data.getSeconds() :
    data.getSeconds();

  //alert(horas + minutos + segundos);
  $horas.text("dafuck");
  $minutos.text(minutos);
  $segundos.text(segundos);
}

pegaHora();
window.setInterval(pegaHora, 1000);
```

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fundo {
  background-color: bisque;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.caixa {
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border: solid 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="relogio" class="fundo">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="horas"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="minutos"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 caixa" id="segundos"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Estou só abrindo no chrome (já limpei o cache). No opera tbm não funcionar. Não aparece erro no console. Coloquei uma imagem, o texto não aparece nas divs

Comment: Bem estranho, pq o código está correto, aliás muito bem escrito, simples e eficaz. Realmente não sei o pq não está funcionando aí.

Answer (score 0):

Estranho era para funcionar, então tenta usar o `.html()` e veja se funciona.

```
$horas.html("dafuck");
    $minutos.html(minutos);
    $segundos.html(segundos);
```

Faça essa alteração e veja se funciona.