# Ordem de execução (Assincrono)?

Tags: javascript

```
function populate () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        guess('btn' + i);
    }
}

function guess(id) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log(button.innerHTML);
    }
}

populate();
```

Como funciona a ordem de execução desse código ? E porque eu tenho que colocar meu  no body pra funcionar, e não no head?

Comment: Veja [O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%c3%a9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%c3%a1-lo)

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre $(document).ready() e window.onload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182797/18246)

Comment: Sobre a sua segunda pergunta: no head o seu código é carregado bem cedo (antes da página propriamente dita ser montada pelo browser) e portanto, o método `guess` não vai encontrar os elementos com os id's informados. Fazendo a chamada pelo body a página já vai ter carregado quando o script for executado e por isso funciona como esperado.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de carregar esses id's antes ? E é recomendado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem nada de assíncrono nesse código, você deve estar se confundindo com a ordem em que os arquivos são carregados no seu navegador (o que é um processo assíncrono).

> E porque eu tenho que colocar meu no body pra funcionar, e não no
> head?

Depende de como você está incluindo o *script* no *HTML*. Se você está incluindo de forma *inline* (escrevendo o script no mesmo arquivo), o script será executado de imediato. Isso significa que o `getElementById` só conseguirá buscar elementos que já foram carregados, portanto esses elementos precisam estar declarados antes do *script*.

Se o *script* está declarado em outro arquivo, no estilo

```
<script src="meuscript.js"></script>
```

Isso significa que ele será carregado em uma requisição diferente, de forma assíncrona. Isso significa que até ele ser carregado, é possível que todo o seu HTML já esteja carregado/processado, e por isso, mesmo que o *script* esteja declarado no *head*, é provável (mas não é garantido) que ele consiga ler elementos do *body* com o `getElementById`.

Para esses casos você precisa pode usar atributos no elemento do script, ou no JavaScript, para que o código só seja executado depois que o HTML já esteja carregado.

Comment: Pesquisei agora com base na sua resposta e achei O DEFER, e realmente funcionou, mas é recomendado usar o DEFER ou colocar o script no body mesmo ?